# Proving existence of local/global extrema of a real-valued function

Tags: real-analysis

I am given the function $f(x) = 2x^2 - 16x + 36, x \in \mathbb{R}$, and asked to show and prove the existence of any local/global extrema. My approach is as follows:

> $f$ has extrema at all points $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ where $f'(x_i) = 0.$
> $$ f'(x) = 4x-16 $$
> $$ 0 = 4(x - 4) $$
> $ \therefore f'(x) = 0 $ for $ x_0 = 4$. At $x_0 = 4$, the gradient of $f$ changes from negative to positive, so we have a local **minimum**.

(I showed this using a number line on $f'(x)$ where I marked $-\infty$, $4$, and $\infty$ and marking whether $f'(x)$ was positive or negative for the respective intervals $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$.

The next steps are to show that:

1. $x_0$ is in fact, a global minimum.
2. State that $f(x)$ has no local maxima, and therefore no global maximum.

For 1: By definition, a function $f$ has a global minimum at a point $a$, such that $f(a) \leq f(x), \forall x\in dom(f)$. Is there an easier way to justify this than as follows?

> $f(x_0) = 4$ $\therefore$ we solve $2x^2 -16x+36 < 4$ to check whether $x_0$ is a global maximum. $$ 2x^2 - 16x + 36 < 4 $$ $$ \iff 2x^2 - 16x + 32 < 0 $$ $$ x^2 - 8x +16 < 0 $$
> This is a contradiction, as the discriminant evaluates to $0$.

2. Is this a valid statement? Or do I need to make a statement about the concavity and limits towards negative and positive infinity?

> Since the critical point $x_0 = 4$ was shown to be a minimum, there are no local maxima $\therefore$ no global maximum.

I'd really appreciate any thoughts anyone has on simplifying the proof, or strengthening it where it needs to be strengthened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2x^{2}-16 x+32=2(x-4)^{2}\ge 0$. Adding $4$ to both sides give s $f(x) \ge 4=f(4)$. So $f$ has  global (hence also, local) minimum at $4$. Since there derivative does not vanish at any point other than $4$ it follows that $f$ has no local (or global) maximum at any point.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think that my proof is valid as is?

Comment: Your first part is correct if you change $<$ to $\le $. @PriyamTurakhia